# Appending numpy arrays into a text file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a function which returns a 2 Dimensional numpy array and this function will be inside a loop. At each iteration, I want to append this numpy array into a file.

```
filename = "xyz"
for i in range(10):
      np_array = function_to_get_numpy()
      now append this `np_array` into filename
```

I can continue to append the numpy array in the script and dump once, but I want to avoid that.

Also I would prefer to store this in non-binary format.

Comment: `np.savetxt` writes a `csv` style output.  It can take a file name, or an opened file.  If you open the file in append mode, you can write to the same file multiple times.  Alternatively you could format each 'row' of the array how ever you want, and use a normal file write.  For text files, regular Python file writes are just fine (even `print` with a `file` parameter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [64]: with open('xyz','w') as f:
    ...:     for n in range(1,4):
    ...:         arr = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)
    ...:         np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%5d', delimiter=',')
    ...:         
In [65]: cat xyz
    0
    0,    1
    2,    3
    0,    1,    2
    3,    4,    5
    6,    7,    8
```

If the number of columns varies, as it does here, it will be hard(er) to read.  `csv` readers like `genfromtxt` won't like it.

If the number of columns is consistent, it can be loaded as one big array.  Separating the writes and reloading them is possible, but more involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take the opportunity to plug `nppretty`, a pretty printer for numpy that I've been working on. It provides a class `ArrayStream` that I think will do exactly what you need.

Install `nppretty` with:

```
pip install nppretty
```

You can use `ArrayStream` much like a file object. For example, this code:

```
from nppretty import ArrayStream
import numpy as np

arrstr = ArrayStream('arraystream.txt', name='arr2D')
for i in range(10):
    arr = np.arange(10*i, 10*(i + 1))
    arrstr.write(arr.reshape(2,5))
arrstr.close()
```

will produce a text file called `arraystream.txt` with the following contents:

```
arr2D = [
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
[35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
[45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
[55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
[65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
[70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
[75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
[85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
[95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
]
```

#### Notes on `ArrayStream`

`ArrayStream` accepts all of the same arguments as the standard Python `open` method. The one additional keyword arg is `name`, which sets the name of the array in the file (`name` defaults to `"array"` if left blank). Just like the file object returned by a call to `open`, an `ArrayStream` instance can used in a `with` statement. For example, the following code will produce the same output as above:

```
with ArrayStream('arraystream.txt', name='arr2D') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        arr = np.arange(10*i, 10*(i + 1))
        f.write(arr.reshape(2,5))
```